# Why is this code compiled without errors? Is it a gcc bug?

Tags: c

The below code is being compiled successfully even though char* name declaration inside the struct is without semicolon.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct map
{
   int id;
   char *name
}map;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the gcc version is 4.8.4 (  (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) )

Comment: Considering the `}` after the declaration leaves no question about the meaning of code, the fact that GCC ignores the error might as well be considered a feature rather than an issue... ;-)

Comment: gcc version 5.4.0 reports it as a warning (*"test.c:7:1: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union"*). Given that the missing semicolon doesn't change the meaning of the code, I think it is reported properly, for anyone that cares.

Comment: gcc 4.8.4: `test.c:15:1: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union [enabled by default]` with `gcc -std=c11 test.c` Please provide proof it does not on your host, as it looks you missed something.

Comment: Time to file a bug report

Comment: @savram: 1) 4.8.4 is quite old already. 2) It **does** generate an error message. Don't recommend a bug report if there if a quick check tells different.

Comment: @Olaf Just out of curiosity, does it generate an error without the `c11` flag?

Comment: @Taelsin: It does. (Not that one should compile as a 18 years obsolete version anyway)

Comment: without typedef like the same code is giving error error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
    char *name

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for `struct` and `union` declarations as of C2011:

```
struct-or-union-specifier:
    struct-or-union identifieropt { struct-declaration-list }
    struct-or-union identifier

struct-or-union:
    struct
    union

struct-declaration-list:
    struct-declaration
    struct-declaration-list struct-declaration

struct-declaration:
    specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-listopt ;
    static_assert-declaration

specifier-qualifier-list:
    type-specifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
    type-qualifier specifier-qualifier-listopt

struct-declarator-list:
    struct-declarator
    struct-declarator-list , struct-declarator

struct-declarator:
    declarator
    declaratoropt : constant-expression

static_assert-declaration:
    _Static_assert ( constant-expression , string-literal ) ;
```

<sub>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.7.2.1*</sub>

It's pretty unambiguous - each declaration in the *`struct-declaration-list`* *must* be terminated with a `;` - there's no allowance for eliding the semicolon before the closing `}`.  Unless you're somehow suppressing it, gcc *should* emit a diagnostic here.  '

**Edit**

Myst raises a valid point here - gcc issues a warning, but doesn't halt translation and still generates the executable (unless I specify `-Werror` or something like that).  However, *why* it does so has nothing to do with 6.7.2.1/8.  The reason is that this particular syntax error is relatively easy to recover from - the required semicolon is missing, but since the next token is the closing `}` of the `struct` or `union` definition, the compiler can safely assume it's seen a valid member declaration and move on. gcc issues a warning (because diagnostics *must* be issued on syntax violations), but there's no reason to halt translation at this point.

The passage Myst quoted has to do with situations like

```
struct foo;

struct bar {
  struct foo blah;
};
```

The `struct foo` type is not yet *complete* when we try to declare the `blah` member; the compiler has no idea how much space to set aside for it.  `struct foo` won't be complete until we see the closing `}` of its definition, so we cannot create an *instance* of `struct foo` until then.

To expand on a point I made somwhere in the comments, the C standard doesn't distinguish between "warnings" and "errors" - it only mandates that a diagnostic *of some sort* be issued on a syntax error or constraint violation:

> **5.1.1.3 Diagnostics**
> 1    A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in
> an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
> contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
> specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be
> produced in other circumstances.<sup>9)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>9) The intent is that an implementation should identify the nature of, and where possible localize, each
> violation. Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a
> valid program is still correctly translated. It may also successfully translate an invalid program.</sup>

Individual compilers can decide whether a particular diagnostic counts as a "warning" or an "error", and they can decide whether to stop translation on a particular error or not.  Like the passage says above, a compiler is allowed to translate an invalid program.

Comment: It does! The problem cannot be reproduced (with the same version). Either this is not the original code or there is some other problem.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer as well as to post a counter argument with regards to your point of view. I should note that, IMHO and although I subscribe to your point of view, the mere existence of a possible counter argument is a good enough reason for the compiler to raise a warning instead of an error.

Comment: @Myst: You are argumenting about ships while the subject is about fishing nets. There is no ambiouity, simply because what you are refering to does not apply. The member declaration is already complete (with the semicolon) if that what you wrote applies.

Comment: @Myst - the standard doesn't distinguish between "warnings" and "errors"; it only mandates that a diagnostic be issued.  The final form of that diagnostic (and any action taken)  is up to the compiler. It may be relatively easy to recover from this error, so gcc just issues a warning and continues translation; a different compiler may decide to class it as an error and halt translation.

Comment: @JohnBode - I gave up the argument, as suggested by Olaf. I would point out that I was never claiming that the standard allows this or that the standard requires that a warning be raised. I claimed that compiler developers, faced with: 1. this textual ambiguity that contradicts the head of that same section in the standard; and 2. the obvious meaning of the code; have a good reason to prefer a warning over an error.

Comment: @Myst: I already made clear the compiler **does** generate a diagnostic. So apparently the compiler developers had no problem understanding what the standard requires. For the warning vs. error, see above. I'll stop this here, too.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the issue might be related to the C11 standard (I don't have the older versions any more, but it might be the same), where it specifies (6.7.2.1 paragraph 8):

> The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation unit. The struct-declaration-list is a sequence of declarations for the members of the structure or union. If the struct-declaration-list does not contain any named members, either directly or via an anonymous structure or anonymous union, the behavior is undefined. **The type is incomplete until immediately after the `}` that terminates the list, and complete thereafter**.

This means that two actions are being performed:

1. Termination of the list (the struct-declaration-list).
2. Completion of the type (the struct or union).

I think this could be (erroneously) constructed to mean that `}` can terminate the struct-declaration-list by also acting as a semi-colon closure that terminates a struct-declaration node.

Otherwise, one could argue, there should have been a single action (completion of the type) rather than two (termination of the struct-declaration-list + completion of the type).

This permissive interpretation (which might not reflect the authors intent, IMHO) makes this into a questionable permissive language interpretation feature rather than an issue.

**Either way**, current versions of both `clang` and `gcc` report **warnings** if a semi-colon is missing (when using the c11 flag). This shows uniformity in the behavior, which suggests that this is an interpretation of the standard rather than a bug.

Considering this possible ambiguity and the fact that the `}` after the declaration leaves no question about the meaning of code, I think compiler developers preference to raise a warning rather than an error is definitely legitimate and no error report is required.

**EDIT**

I read John Bode's answer and Olaf's comments and edited my answer accordingly, to make my point of view somewhat clearer.

Although both John and Olaf are far wiser than myself and although I see the merit in their point of view, I don't think the standard is clear enough on this point.

It's true that the detailed quote in John's answer defines every `struct-declaration` as clearly ending with a semi-colon (`;`), meaning the list should end with a semi-colon.

However, the textual explanation in that same section seems to suggest that the `}` has a possible dual function.

This suggested room for interpretation is probably too permissive, however this is a good enough reason to **raise a warning instead of an error** when compiling the code (IMHO) - especially as the code itself can't be misinterpreted.

Comment: i think in any version of gcc ,it should give error at compile time.

Comment: @JayBhaskar - although I agree from a maintainer's point of view... the fact that the mainstream compilers behave in a mostly uniform way (producing a warning rather than an error) makes it good enough IMHO. If something compiles (with warnings or without) on `gcc`, I would expect it to compile on `clang` and vise verses. Besides, if the standard can be understood in a permissive way, compiler developers don't really have much of a choice.

Comment: No - the language syntax demands that every member declaration in a `struct` or `union` be terminated with a `;`.  *Complete* means something different here.

Comment: "I think this could be constructed to mean that } can terminate the list" - No. It means you cannot use that type in the declaration itself (recursive strctures). And that's basically (if not literally) the same as in previous versions.

Comment: @Olaf, I think the restriction you're point out refers to the "and complete" part of the sentence (you cannot include incomplete types in a structure or union).

Comment: @Myst. I refer to the part you emphasised. I thought that was obvious. It has nothing to do with the declarations of each member apparently. That's not how language grammar specifications work actually.

Comment: @Olaf  - both actions are in the part I emphasized: "terminates the list" &  "complete [the type]".

Comment: @Myst: It does not say it terminates a member-declaration. You might want to read the other answer and the standard more carefully.

Comment: @Olaf - I understand your point of view and I think the correct way to read the standard is to require the semi-colon. However, as I detailed in my edited answer, the added action performed by the `}` (in the textual explanation) and it's possible conflict with the head of the section are (IMHO) a good enough reason to raise a warning instead of an error (which is what my answer is all about).

Comment: @Myst: _sigh_ You are discussion about nonsense. Just read the comments. gcc **does** warn. I checked this myself. It is exactly this version with default warnings options! OP simply has either ignored the warning or a completely different problem. And that citation of your's is not related to the member declarators! There is nothing unclear about his part of the standard That's all I have to say, I give up. Feel free to continue with `/dev/null`